# how to use MemoryCache Class to cache and get a list in asp.net core

Tags: c#, caching, .net-core, memorycache

I can Get a Cached object by creating an instance of 'IMeomoryCache' class Like this:

```
_memoryCache.Get<Users>(id);
```

1.but how can I get a list of Users using this Class?

2.the second question is how to set the list cached if it was not cached?

Comment: You can find how to do it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the TryGetValue method that returns the cached object as an output parameter. Refer the example below:-

```
List<User> users;
string key = "usersCacheKey";
//TryGetValue will get the item from cache and assign it to users variable.
//It will return false if item is not found.
if(!_memoryCache.TryGetValue<List<User>>(key, out users){
  //item not found in cache. set the cache item here
  users = new List<User>();
  _memoryCache.Set<List<User>>(key, users);
}
```

Reference below link(s) fro more information on how to use Memory Caching in ASP.NET Core 5.0:-
[Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0)